# How to view compose preview in landscape mode

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I need to make the design for landscape mode hence I need the preview mode in landscape but I could not find how it can be done . Kindly help me on it by default the preview is shown in the image[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can play around with the `heightDp` and `widthDp` parameters of the `@Preview` annotation to manually create a landscape orientation. Below is a quick demo from an app that I'm working on.

```kotlin
@Preview(heightDp = 360, widthDp = 800)
@Composable
fun MyPreview() {

}
```

[image: Landscape preview in compose]